# The difference between claimed return type and the actual one

Tags: c++, function, reference

What is the difference between functions f2 and f3 in the following code? Especially what is wrong with f3() since there is a warning at compilation where it is marked?

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

class A {
public:
  int m_a ;
} ;

A f2 ( A& a ) { return a ;}

A& f3 ( A a ) { 
    return a ; // a warning here:
    // reference to stack memory associated with local
    // variable 'a' returned
} 

int main () {

  A a ;
  a.m_a = 3 ;

  A b = f2 ( a ) ;
  b.m_a = 5 ;
  std::cout << b.m_a << " " << a.m_a << std::endl ;

  A& c = f3 ( a ) ;
  c.m_a = 5 ;
  std::cout << c.m_a << " " << a.m_a << std::endl ;

  return 0 ;
} // the output is "3 5" repeated in two lines
```

In the above code, both f2 and f3 have inconsistency in the claimed return type and the actual one. I wonder how it works. Thanks!

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with types. Some things can be returned from functions while other things *of the same exact type* cannot.

Comment: You misunderstood the forces at play here. There's no *"inconsistency in the return type"*. `f2` promises to return an `A`  by value, and it does so by copying from the referenced object it was passed. `f3` promises to return a reference and it does, to a local object it received by value. But alas the object goes out of scope when `f3` returns, and so the reference it returns is no longer valid